# How to get current spinner value with databinding?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, spinner

I'm using MVVM pattern with Databinding in Andriod. I set values to spinner and it works, but how can i get selected item/position in ViewModel?

What I did:

1. Set parametr android:selectedItemPosition="@={viewModel.position}"
   to my spinner in xml
2. Create public int position in ViewModel
3. Create getter and setter for position
4. Create InverseBindingAdapter

   ```
   @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:selectedItemPosition")
    public int SelectedItem(Spinner spinner) {
        position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        return position;
   ```

   }

but it still not working. What should I do? I get crazy with this binding

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:selectedItemPosition` from xml and bind it to your model in ViewModel like below as an example

```
android:selectedItemPosition="@={viewModel.model.selectedPosition}"
```

Comment: Did you try? Its working for me though it says unknown

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter/issues/100

Comment: @Asaduzzaman, No, android:selectedItemPosition is not working for me.